# Bernouilli trial? not sure

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Suppose a box, with 100 balls where 3 of them are black. No replacement.

The odds of not picking a black ball after 10 balls are prod ((97-n)/(100-n)) from n=0 to n=9;
the odds of picking 1 black ball after 10 trials are 3/91;
the odds of picking 2 black balls after 10 trials are ((3/92)*(2/91)).

What are the odds of picking less than 2 black balls after take n balls?

*Peter, thanks it's the hypergeometric distribution*

Comment: Just to clarify the problem : We take $10$ balls out of $100$ (from which $3$ are black) without replacement ; what is the probability to draw exactly two black balls ? Right ? In this case, you need the hypergeometric distribution

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  Are you replacing the balls or not?  What does "picking $1$ black ball after $10$ trials" mean?  Where did you get $\frac 3{91}$?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you wish to find the probabilities rather than the [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds).

The probability that exactly $k$ black balls are selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{k}\dbinom{97}{10 - k}}{\dbinom{100}{10}}$$
Hence, the probability that no black balls are selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{0}\dbinom{97}{10}}{\dbinom{100}{10}}$$

The probability that exactly one black ball is selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{97}{9}}{\dbinom{100}{10}}$$

The probability that exactly two blacks balls are selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{97}{8}}{\dbinom{100}{10}}$$

The probability that exactly three black balls are selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{3}\dbinom{97}{0}}{\dbinom{100}{10}}$$

Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, their probabilities should add to $1$, as you can verify.

Finally, the probability that less than two black balls are selected when $10$ balls are selected without replacement is found by adding the results for the probabilities that no black balls are selected and exactly one black ball is selected.